# using ODE45 in MATLAB to solve three PDE's

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve equations 3, 10 and 11 of the following source:http://web.math.ku.dk/~moller/e04/bio/ludwig78.pdf

Below is the code I have produced within MATLAB, however it is not producing a graph displaying the three solutions on the one graph.

```
%% x=(S,N)^T
%%initial value:
x0= [1;1/2];
vopt= odeset('RelTol' ,1e-3, 'AbsTol', 1e-3, 'NormControl' , 'on', 'InitialStep',0.1,'MaxStep',0.5);
beta=20;E=1;r=0.1;K =4*S;P=10;N0=S/2;alpha=1;

%%define the right hand side:
f = @(t,x) r.*x(1).*(1-x(1)./K)-beta.*(N0.*N0./(alpha.^2-N0.^2));
        r.*x(2).*(1-(x(2)./K).*(K./x(3)));
        r.*x(3).*(1-x(3)./K)-P.*(x(1)./x(2))

[t,y] = ode45(f,[0 30],x0,vopt);
figure(1);
plot(t,y(:,1),'N',t,y(:,2),'S',t,y(:,3),'E');
legend('Population of Budworms','Available foliage','Energy Reserve');
```

Comment: The code you have provided is not executable. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: This is not a system of PDEs (and if it was, `ode45` would be of no use). Also, saying "it is not producing a graph" doesn't tell us a lot. Is there an error message? If so, have you read it carefully and tried to fix the problem. Matlab error messages are very helpful, so read it and you will probably be able to solve the problem.

Comment: We can't run your code, `S` is not defined.